# How to share EJB local interface across applications installed on the same WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, local

I'm having a problem with WebSphere Application Server 7. I have 2 applications installed on WAS A & B. B wants to use a local EJB interface of A's.

The module that contains the local EJB interface is part of A's EAR.

What I tried doing was including a reference to the module in my deployment of B. The problem I found was that, while looking up the interface:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
//succeeds
Object obj = ic.lookup("ejblocal:sample.MyEJBLocal");
//fails with ClassCastException
MyEJBLocal localBean = (MyEJBLocal) obj;
```

The program crashes because the Interface has random letters prefixed to the name of the class, e.g.

```
Cannot cast type SL07SMyEJBLocal to MyEJBLocal these types are incompatible.
```

I tried playing around with WAS & I was able to get the cast to succeed by changing the class loader settings for the server from multiple to single.

Q - I don't really like the idea of having one class loader for all the applications on my server - is there another way to get the EJB local interface to be shared across application A & B?

Answer (score 1):

See the "Local client views" section of the [EJB modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cejb_emod.html) module of the InfoCenter (I've linked to the 8.5 InfoCenter, but the advice applies to all versions).  Basically, in order to share a local interface, you must ensure that both applications have a view of the same class.  The most common approach is to use a server-associated shared library.  Note carefully the other caveats of sharing a local EJB across applications.

Comment: I did as you suggested & created a shared library. I made the changes to both EAR projects deployment descriptors in the shared library section. I also put a reference in WAS for the jar containing the interface, into the classpath field of the shared library. I then added this to the classloader shared library references.However when I lookup the interface I still get a ClassCastException

Comment: Are you using "parent last" class loading?  Is the shared library associated with a server class loader (per the InfoCenter doc)?  What do ejb.getClass().getClassLoader() and MyEJBLocal.getClassLoader() say?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to remove the client-view class files from the EARs? If the client-view class files are located inside the EAR, they will be loaded from there, even if you have them in the shared library.

Comment: @Isacc That will only happen if OP is using "parent last".  Otherwise, it should be loaded from the configured server class loader.